# C# Generics Inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following class

```
public class AccountingBase<TItemType> where TItemType : AccountingItemBase
```

And in my AccountingItemBase i have the following property:

```
public virtual AccountingBase<AccountingItemBase> Parent { get; set; }
```

in my AccountingBase, I am trying to do the following

```
item.Parent = this;
```

Logically this should work, as TItemType inherits from AccountingItemBase, but instead i get the following error:

```
> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'TGS.MySQL.DataBaseObjects.AccountingBase<TItemType>'
> to
> 'TGS.MySQL.DataBaseObjects.AccountingBase<TGS.MySQL.DataBaseObjects.AccountingItemBase>'
```

How can i set the child properties parent property to itself (inside the parent class)

Comment: dumb question, can I see the declaration (including namespaces) for `TItemType` ?

Comment: @drachenstern: dumb question, which? The OP or yours? :->

Comment: @drachenstern: `TItemType` is a type parameter. It doesn't have a separate declaration.

Comment: @hermeister der welten ~ Mine.

Comment: somebody just mark me down for a /facepalm day ... I have a feeling I'll be doing it over and over ... and over .. and over ... where's my coffee?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, your intuition is incorrect. It shouldn't work, because generic classes aren't variant in .NET.

Just because `TItemType` inherits from `AccountingItemBase` doesn't mean that `AccountingBase<TItemType>` inherits from `AccountingBase<AccountingItemBase>`. Suppose `AccountingBase<TItemType>` had a field of type `TItemType`. Then if your intuition were correct, you could write:

```
AccountingBase<SomeSubtype> x = new AccountingBase<SomeSubtype>();
AccountingBase<AccountingItemBase> y = x;
y.SomeField = new OtherSubtype();
```

That would clearly break type safety, because when looked at as an `AccountingBase<SomeSubtype>`, the field is meant to be of type `SomeSubtype`, but you've put a value of type `OtherSubtype` in there!

Basically, generic variance is a complex topic.

I suggest you read Eric Lippert's long and detailed [blog post series](https://ericlippert.com/category/covariance-and-contravariance/) for more information. Or I have a video from [NDC 2010](http://streaming.ndc2010.no) which you may find useful. Basically in .NET 4 there's *some* generic variance, but it's limited.

Now, as to what you can do in your situation:

- You could create a *nongeneric* base class which `AccountingBase` inherits from. That's probably the best idea. Then make the type of the `Parent` property that nongeneric type.
- You could make `AccountingBase` generic in both itself and its parent... but that ends up causing recursion issues, effectively...

Comment: @Alexander: No, but I like to view my writing in general as teaching of a sort.

Comment: @Jon Skeet ~ And well you do sir. I for one would hate to see you go. PS: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55711#55711

Comment: Thanks for the great answer skeet, i originally designed my AccoutningBaseItem generic type to overcome this issue(so that the AccountingBaseItem knows what subclass it is), but that started annoying me that i have to pass an extra type for no reason around and it didn't feel like it was properly designed. I will do what you suggested in your first point, making the accountingbase inherit from non generic type. Thanks for the links, i will read them first.

Comment: @Alexander, was that a compliment or not? :)

Comment: @Benjol, actually I had felt a strong lack of such professionals in the University I spent 4 years in. In contrast, I got acquainted to a lot of local professionals, who don't teach to students what they know. I find it a bit cruel. I donno, just asking.

Comment: I implemented the nongeneric base successfully,  but now i have a runtime problem with nhibernate i am trying to debug with no luck so far. As it works when i step through the program but fails on loading the domain object when run without pauses, which makes it that much harder :( Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Jon's options, you could:

- Create an interface `IAccountingBase` that provides only the limited access required by AccountingItemBase to do its work (similar to a non-generic base class, but further abstracted.)
- Restructure your code so that AccountingItemBase doesn't need a Parent reference to do its work.  My experience has been that circular dependencies (Owner knows about Items which know about Owner) are symptomatic of a design where the Child instances are taking on too many responsibilities.  You can sometimes get around this by moving the functionality to the Parent or by moving it to higher-level classes that perform complex operations on multiple Items in the context of a single Parent, eliminating the need for each Item to have a Parent reference.  For instance, if your Items expose functions related to Account reconciliation, you might have an AccountReconciler class rather than putting the functions on the Items.

Comment: I need the parent reference because it is used to store in the database, so that NHibernate knows which AccountingItem it belongs to when saving/udpating.