# Generics inheritance compile error

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm getting a compile error when I try  to compile this

The type 'WpfApplication2.CommandInstrumentTrade' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'WpfApplication2.GenericWindowBase'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'WpfApplication2.CommandInstrumentTrade' to 'WpfApplication2.GenericCommandBase'

```
public interface IBaseClass
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass : IBaseClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
}

public class Command
{
}

public class GenericCommandBase<T> : Command where T : IBaseClass
{
}

public class DerivedGenericCommand : GenericCommandBase<DerivedClass>
{
}

public class GenericWindowBase<T> where T : GenericCommandBase<IBaseClass>
{
}

public class DerivedGenericWindow : GenericWindowBase<DerivedGenericCommand> // this line fails
{

}
```

Comment: The error doesn't match your sample code. The error says you are using `GenericWindowBase<CommandInstrumentTrade> `, which fails because `CommandInstrumentTrade` does not satisfy the where condition of `GenericWindowBase`.

Comment: Inheritance doesn't compose with generics. Just because `Base` and `Derived` have an inheritance relationship doesn't mean that `Generic<Base>` and `Generic<Derived>` do.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right but is there workaround for this?

Comment: Not sure. Might be easier if the question's code wasn't so abstract. I've got *no* idea what concrete problem you're trying to solve, and how you thought that this (attempted) structure would solve it for you.

Comment: Search for covariance/contravariance, there are plenty of questions like these on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `Generic<Derived>` does not satisfy the condition `where T : Generic<Base>`. Even if `Derived` derives from `Base`, `Generic<Derived>` does not derive from `Generic<Base>`

There are many questions like that in StackOverflow.
Try reading those:

1. [C# Generics Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043702/c-sharp-generics-inheritance)
2. [generic inheritance in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748706/generic-inheritance-in-c)

Inheritance doesn't compose with generics. You need to create some kind of converter from one to another. Maybe if you present some less abstract code we could help You